# KendoUI implemention issue

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I have a combo box and a check box in a page. Also, I used KendoUi library.
The combo box has two options (0% and 100%) and if the check box is checked the combo box value would be 100%. The problem is, Kendoui library hide the main combo box and generate its own elements look like the combo box. However, by clicking check box the generated combo box's value isn't changed( not the original combo box).
My question is:
Is it possible to implement "KendoUi" library on some elements not all in a page?

Comment: If the question is if it is possible, the answer is: Yes, it is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your HTML code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        Combobox:
        <select id="combo"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            100%:
            <input id="hundred" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option1"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript initialization of the combobox:

```
$("#combo").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField : "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource    : [
        { text: "0", value: "1" },
        { text: "100%", value: "2" }
    ]
});
```

You should define a handler for changes in the checkbox as follow:

```
$("#hundred").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#combo").data("kendoComboBox").value(2)
    }
})
```

Where I intercept any change of the combobox and if it is checked then I set the value of the combobox to `2` that according with previous definition is `100%`.

JSFiddle showing it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/uA6F3/

Comment: Thanks OnaBai, but my main question is: if there is any way to apply kendoui on some controls not all of them? and how?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by _apply kendoui on some controls not all_

Comment: I got a page which kendoui is applied to all controls including 3 cobo box. but I need to unbind one of them. I need to know how it is possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that is supported. You should invoke `destroy()` for the combobox plus remove all the decoration that Kendo UI introduces around a Combobox (not done by `destroy`). Is it not possible to initialize everything but this? Why do you want to remove it?